# How to UnitTest two input textboxes with same name in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a code where there are two fields with same input names like shown below

```
<input ng-if="max_length == 5" type="text" name="zipcode" value="" ng-model="store_zip.zipcode" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-maxlength="max_length" required>
<input ng-if="max_length == 7" type="text" name="zipcode" value="" ng-model="store_zip.zipcode" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ng-maxlength="max_length" required>
```

How to write Angular JS Unit TestCase for this?

My below code looks something like this but it's not working and it throws a error message saying `SetView` Value is undefined

```
 it('with a Invalid ZipCode -75678', function () 
    {
                form.zipcode.$setViewValue('75678');
                $scope.$digest();
                expect(form.zipcode.$valid).toBe(true);
                expect(createsiteform.zipcode.$error.maxlength).toBe(undefined);
                expect(form.zipcode.$error.pattern).toBe(true);
    });
```

Comment: Have you set the `max_length` scope variable to either 5 or 7? Ng-if removes the element from the DOM if the expression is false, which would make `form.zipcode` become undefined.

Comment: How to set max_length is 5 via UnitTesting script? Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you could simply set it with `$scope.max_length = 5` during test setup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nikoj's comment,

I found out the setting the expression value solves the problem.In my case max_length is the expression

```
   $scope.$apply('max_length=5');
```